# Registering for iOS 7 notifications in swift

Tags: ios7, notifications, xcode6

I want to be able to have notifications on iOS 7 and iOS 8, I've set up it with ios8 successfully but this iOS 7 I get an error of just "lldb" nothing else on the line "var mySettings...". From what I've read this is how you are meant to register it on iOS 7 but it doesn't seem to work!

```
   func application(application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [NSObject: AnyObject]?) -> bool{

    //check if its on ios8

    var deviceVersion :  NSString = UIDevice.currentDevice().systemVersion



    if deviceVersion.floatValue >= 8.0 {

     //I've set up the iOS 8 notifications here and that all works.

    }else{



        var types : UIUserNotificationType = UIUserNotificationType.Badge | UIUserNotificationType.Alert;



        var mySettings : UIUserNotificationSettings = UIUserNotificationSettings(forTypes: types, categories: nil)



        UIApplication.sharedApplication().registerUserNotificationSettings(mySettings)



    }





    return true

}
```

Answer (score 2):

Your issue is:

UIApplication.sharedApplication().registerUserNotificationSettings(mySettings)

This is not supported in ios 7. You should implement something like this:

```
func application(application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: NSDictionary?) -> Bool {
// Override point for customization after application launch.
if(UIApplication.instancesRespondToSelector(Selector("registerUserNotificationSettings:")))
{
    application.registerUserNotificationSettings(UIUserNotificationSettings(forTypes: UIUserNotificationType.Sound | UIUserNotificationType.Alert | UIUserNotificationType.Badge, categories: nil))
}
else
{
   //do ios7 stuff here. If you are using just local notifications then you dont need to do anything. for remote notifications:
application.registerForRemoteNotificationTypes(UIUserNotificationType.Sound | UIUserNotificationType.Alert | UIUserNotificationType.Badge)
}
return true
}
```