# Azure + Swift Push Notifications

Tags: ios, swift, azure, push-notification

I am trying to make a VERY simple PUSH from a remote server to an app.

I have set up a notification hub on Azure as per [1], but I cannot get a debug message down to the device. **I DO NOT WANT TO READ / WRITE FROM A DB TABLE USING MOBILE SERVICES**

I am doing this in Swift, and I have found **nothing** on the internet that actually receives a push from a server is iOS swift as a complete tutorial.

I do not know, for example, how to write the following code in swift:

```
- (void)application:(UIApplication *)application didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken:(NSData *)deviceToken {
    // TODO: update @"MobileServiceUrl" and @"AppKey" placeholders
    MSClient *client = [MSClient clientWithApplicationURLString:@"MobileServiceUrl" applicationKey:@"AppKey"];

    [client.push registerNativeWithDeviceToken:deviceToken tags:@[@"uniqueTag"] completion:^(NSError *error) {
        if (error != nil) {
            NSLog(@"Error registering for notifications: %@", error);
        }
    }];
}
```

So far this is my code in my AppDelegate (some of the code I got from [2]):

```
    var client: MSClient?

func application(application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [NSObject: AnyObject]?) -> Bool {
    if(UIApplication.instancesRespondToSelector(Selector("registerUserNotificationSettings:")))
    {
        application.registerUserNotificationSettings(UIUserNotificationSettings(forTypes: UIUserNotificationType.Sound | UIUserNotificationType.Alert | UIUserNotificationType.Badge, categories: nil))
    }
    /*else
    {
    //do ios7 stuff here. If you are using just local notifications then you dont need to do anything. for remote notifications:
    application.registerForRemoteNotificationTypes(UIUserNotificationType.Sound | UIUserNotificationType.Alert | UIUserNotificationType.Badge)
    }*/

    self.client = MSClient(applicationURLString: "[url]", applicationKey: "[key]")

    UIApplication.sharedApplication().registerForRemoteNotifications()
    let settings = UIUserNotificationSettings(forTypes: .Alert, categories: nil)
    UIApplication.sharedApplication().registerUserNotificationSettings(settings)

    return true
}

func application(application: UIApplication, didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken deviceToken: NSData) {
    println("Got device token \(deviceToken)");
    //IS THIS EVEN CORRECT???? [3] and [4]
    /*let json = ("{\"platform\":\"ios\", \"deviceToken\":\"\(deviceToken)\"}" as NSString).dataUsingEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding)

    self.client?.invokeAPI("register_notifications", data: json, HTTPMethod: "POST", parameters: nil, headers: nil, completion:nil)*/
    let registrationTags: [String] = ["tag"];
    //EDIT 1 - I HAVE MADE A LITTLE PROGRESS
    self.client?.push.registerNativeWithDeviceToken(deviceToken, tags: registrationTags, completion: { (error) -> Void in
        println("Error registering")
    })
}

func application(application: UIApplication, didFailToRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithError error: NSError) {
    println("Could not register \(error)");
}

func application(application: UIApplication, didReceiveRemoteNotification userInfo: [NSObject : AnyObject]) {
    println("Remote notification received!")
    println("Awesome!")
}
```

I am getting a device token back, which means I should be registered, but I do not know how to properly implement [code]

```
self.client?.push.registerNativeWithDeviceToken(deviceToken: deviceToken, tags: registrationTags, completion: [code])
```

**EDIT 1** I have made some progress here:

```
self.client?.push.registerNativeWithDeviceToken(deviceToken, tags: registrationTags, completion: { (error) -> Void in
        println("Error registering")
    })
```

Now I get an error with registering:

> Error Domain=com.Microsoft.WindowsAzureMobileServices.ErrorDomain Code=-1302 "Error: Internal Server Error" UserInfo=0x14d97b10 {NSLocalizedDescription=Error: Internal Server Error, com.Microsoft.WindowsAzureMobileServices.ErrorResponseKey= { URL: https://[servicename].azure-mobile.net/push/registrations%3FdeviceId=[longnumber]&platform=apns } { status code: 500, headers {
>       "Cache-Control" = "no-cache";
>       "Content-Length" = 51;
>       "Content-Type" = "application/json";
>       Date = "Thu, 05 Mar 2015 08:52:10 GMT";
>       Server = "Microsoft-IIS/8.0";
>       "Set-Cookie" = "ARRAffinity=[somehash];Path=/;Domain=[servicename].azure-mobile.net";
>       "X-Powered-By" = "ASP.NET";
>       "x-zumo-version" = "Zumo.master.0.1.6.4217.Runtime";
>   } }, com.Microsoft.WindowsAzureMobileServices.ErrorRequestKey= { URL: https://[servicename].azure-mobile.net/push/registrations%3FdeviceId=[longnumber]&platform=apns }}

**EDIT 2**

I have now made the following changes after reading [5]:

```
    func application(application: UIApplication, didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken deviceToken: NSData) {
        let token = NSString(data: deviceToken, encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding)
        println("Got device token");        

        let hub = SBNotificationHub(connectionString: CONNECTIONSTRING, notificationHubPath: HUBPATH)
        hub.registerNativeWithDeviceToken(deviceToken, tags: nil, completion: {(error) -> Void in
            println("Error registering: \(error)")
        })
    }
```

And the output I now see is:

> Got device token
>   Error registering: nil

I feel like I am making progress but when I send the debug push from Azure I see nothing in my logs (currently when I receive a push I just print a message)
References:
[1] http://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/notification-hubs-ios-get-started/
[2] [Registering for iOS 7 notifications in swift](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28420874/registering-for-ios-7-notifications-in-swift)
[3] https://github.com/Azure/azure-content/blob/master/articles/notification-hubs-ios-mobile-services-register-user-push-notifications.md
[4] http://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/notification-hubs-ios-mobile-services-register-user-push-notifications/
[5] http://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/notification-hubs-ios-get-started/

Comment: your deviceToken is NSData type please convert it to NSString and then use.

Comment: but the signature of registerNativeWithDeviceToken actually wants the NSData! type...

Comment: let token = NSString(data: deviceToken, encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding)//results in nil, even though I am getting back 32 bytes of data which is an NSInlineData type

Comment: remove `angle brackets` from deviceToken

Comment: Could you please point out the angle brackets?

Comment: Turns out Azure just sucks at 1: documentation and 2: actually sending push notifications. I tried Pushwoosh and the experience left a MUCH better taste in my mouth

Comment: I just went through the Azure tutorial and couldn't find any resourse for the Swift integration. Can you please explain how did you included Azure framework for swift. Thanks!

Comment: Oh man that is totally another headache... you will need to import the frameworks by copying them in and then using a bridging header file to import them into the code. This is common practice for swift inclusion so it shouldn't be too hard: https://bohemianpolymorph.wordpress.com/2014/07/11/manually-adding-a-swift-bridging-header/

Comment: But where on earth is the SBNotificationHub you reference... It doesn't appear to be in the WindowsAzureMobileServices.framework... The MS tutorial even has it in the Objective-C code but I don't think it's in there?

Comment: @Darren did you ever find out where the SBNotificationHub exists?...pulling my hair out using Azure, damn it's horrible.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This one worked for me. Hope this may help.

```
var client: MSClient?

func application(application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [NSObject: AnyObject]?) -> Bool {
    #if !TARGET_IPHONE_SIMULATOR
        let notiType:UIUserNotificationType = .Alert | .Badge | .Sound
        let settings = UIUserNotificationSettings(forTypes: notiType, categories: nil)
        UIApplication.sharedApplication().registerUserNotificationSettings(settings)
        UIApplication.sharedApplication().registerForRemoteNotifications()
    #endif

    self.client = MSClient(applicationURLString:"https://yourAppName.azure-mobile.net/", applicationKey:"yourApplicationKey")
    return true
}

func application(application: UIApplication!, didFailToRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithError error: NSError!) {
    println("Failed to register with error: \(error)");
}

func application(application: UIApplication!, didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken deviceToken: NSData!) {
    let hub = SBNotificationHub(connectionString:"yourConnectionString", notificationHubPath:"yourAppName")
    hub.registerNativeWithDeviceToken(deviceToken, tags:nil, completion: { (error) in
        if (error != nil) {
            println("Error registering for notification: \(error)")
        }
    })
}

func application(application: UIApplication!, didReceiveRemoteNotification userInfo:[NSObject : AnyObject]?, fetchCompletionHandler:()) {
    println("Recived: \(userInfo)")
    NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().postNotificationName("ReceivedNotification", object:userInfo)
}
```

Comment: I wouldn't be able to tell you if this was the answer or not... I suppose if it gets enough upvotes I will mark it as the answer. Honestly I tried several different push providers and they worked straight away.

Comment: You don't need to mark this as an answer. I just had the same problem and got a help from what you have tried. Thanks.

Comment: Hi there - I want to mark SOMETHING as an answer - I believe it is good community etiquette (It also affects my stats if I have answers to questions without accepting answers). I am glad that we helped each other :) Do you find that the Azure pushes come through consistently? I actually did get them working, but about 1 in 50 came through. Might be because I am in South Africa and for some reason the first world can't understand that we are a people capable of working more than just a doorbell (jab at Google play merchant accounts, iStore presence, etc etc - not available here)

Comment: For me, the messages came through about 8-9 in 10. I think 1 in 50 is too bad:( As far as I remember, it doesn't push the notification if the message content is the same. So, I changed the message content every time I send the test message.

Comment: Specifically where in the Azure management console do you get the app key from please?

Comment: Andrew, 
1. Select mobile servies icon from left menu
2. Select your mobile service from the list in the center
3. Select your platform (Windows, iOS, Android, ...)
4. Select 'CONNECT AN EXISTING APP'
5. You can see a code snippet containing UrlString and ApplicationKey

Comment: How did you manage to use SBNotificationHub in a swift project, I just can't get the framework to work...

Comment: You don't actually need the MSClient (in case you only have a Notification Hub and not a mobile app)

Comment: @Biniou . Make sure you import correct name in bridging header. 

"#import "WindowsAzureMessaging/WindowsAzureMessaging.h""

Comment: @Young I have different issue. Its working fine in simulator but not working in device.

Answer (score 5):

This worked fine for me:

```
let client: MSClient = MSClient(applicationURLString: "https://yoururl.azure-mobile.net/", applicationKey: "yourApplicationKey")
client.push.registerNativeWithDeviceToken(deviceToken, tags: nil, completion: {(error) -> Void in

  if error != nil{
    NSLog("Error registering for notifications: %@", error)
  }

})
```